# Can't see all the photos in messenger shared media

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chat

I have a messenger chat of about 1 year and there's a lot of shared media. I am able to see all the photos in chat(even the 1 year old ones) but when checking the shared media in messenger, I can't see the ones which are only a couple of months old.

My messenger is updated, and the problem persists even in the web app, but the photos there are a couple more months old

Any suggestions on how I can access all these photos through shared media instead of scrolling all the way in chat?